# How to Display Post View Count

Tags: posts, functions, loop, query-posts

I am trying to display post view counts.

I've tried below function to display the post view count, but I'm getting same post view for all the post in loop. Not getting correct post view count.

**Function:**

```
       <?php
          // function to display number of posts.
           function getPostViews($postID){
           $count_key = 'post_views_count';
                $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
              if($count==''){
          delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
                     add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
                    return "0 View";
            }
            return $count.' Views';
      }             

          // function to count views.
       function setPostViews($postID) {
      $count_key = 'post_views_count';
          $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
     if($count==''){
                 $count = 0;
     delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
               add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
          }else{
     $count++;
                   update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
               }
             }


          // Add it to a column in WP-Admin
     add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'posts_column_views');
       add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_column_views',5,2);
     function posts_column_views($defaults){
      $defaults['post_views'] = __('Views');
     return $defaults; 
        }
       function posts_custom_column_views($column_name, $id){
if($column_name === 'post_views'){
    echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());
      }
       }
     ?>
```

**Loop Code:**

```
   <ul>
      <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=5' ); ?>

        <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
      <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

       <?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>  //post View COde

  <?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 250);?></li>

      <?php endwhile;?>
  </ul>
```

Need suggestions to display Correct Post View Count in while Loop

Comment: Whats the source of the code?

Comment: Can you please explain why you are deleting and then adding view count in `getPostViews` function?

Answer (score 6):

Add this to single.php, and make sure you paste in inside the loop.

```
<?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

Lastly, to display the number of views a post has, just add this where you want it to be displayed:

```
<?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

.

```
<?php

// function to display number of posts.

function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}

// function to count views.
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I used your code and it works fine but I don't know why we have 2 query?
https://uupload.ir/files/bt01_screen_shot_2020-12-01_at_4.57.55_am.png

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing the meta data correctly, then you can use the following code to display the count

```
echo (int) get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'post_views_count', true) . ' View(s)';
```

Answer (score -1):

For the value 0 in `add_post_meta` the view count is not updating. Try the line `add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '1');` instead of line `add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');`.